# Batch windows xp timed prompt without choice.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, prompt, timed

im new to batch scripting. I was wondering if there was a way to write a timed prompt without using choice.exe because I'm using windows xp. Something along the lines of:

```
@echo off
/set p answer=input y or n in 30 seconds
rem start timer
if answer==y(
  goto :action1
)
if answer==n(
  goto action2
)
rem if timer has expired without input go to :action1

:action 1
echo you have entered y
:action 2
echo you have entered n
```

Thank you for the hints.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea.  You could use `Wscript.Shell`'s [`Popup()`](https://ss64.com/vb/popup.html) method.  It includes a timeout parameter.  A Yes / No dialog will return 6 on Yes, 7 on No, and -1 on timeout.  This is easy enough to convert to Boolean as `true` on Yes / timeout, `false` on No.  Save this with a .bat extension and you'll see how it works.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal

set delay=30
set "msg=Do you wish to continue?"

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%msg%" %delay% && (
    goto yes
) || (
    goto no
)

:yes
echo You chose yes.
exit /b

:no
echo You chose no.
exit /b

@end // end Batch / begin JScript hybrid code

var osh = WSH.CreateObject('WScript.Shell'),
    msg = WSH.Arguments(0),
    secs = WSH.Arguments(1);

var response = osh.Popup(msg, secs, 'Waiting for response', 4 + 32);
// yes or timeout returns true; no returns false
WSH.Quit(!(response - 7));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

[EditVar and Choose](http://www.westmesatech.com/editv.html)

> Choose is similar to the Microsoft Choice tool, but it has more features. Here are some reasons why it might be preferable to Choice:
>
> - It doesn't beep when the user makes an invalid choice.
> - It offers a "default key" feature, which lets a user press Enter to select a default choice.
> - It comes with a real-mode DOS version (useful for MS-DOS boot media).
>   The Win32 version's timeout feature doesn't get confused when you run multiple instances in separate console windows (this was a problem with earlier Win32 console versions of Microsoft's Choice tool).
> - A 64-bit version is provided.
> - It can suppress the display of the user's choice.
> - It offers a "line input" mode where the user must press Enter after making a > choice.

This is an example:

```
CHOOOSE64.exe -c YNA -d A -n -p "Prompt" -t A,30
rem           -Choices
rem                  -Default
rem                       -No default prompt
rem                          -Prompt(custom)
rem                                     -timeout defaultChoice, timeout in seconds

if %errorlevel%==1 echo Y
if %errorlevel%==2 echo N
if %errorlevel%==3 echo A or timeout-ed
```